# Unable to execute command 'tasm.exe' with Borland

Tags: inline-assembly, tasm, borland-c++

I'm using Borland 4.52 to build an old project and I'm running into this issue.

When my build script enters a module that contains the assembly code, I have :

```
INFO : root.compile : ==================================================
DEBUG : root.compile : Building module
INFO : root.compile : ==================================================
Cleaning...
INFO : root.compile : Thread Handler said : 1 was created
DEBUG : root.compile : Thread-100 : module_path
c:\make.exe: *** [c_des.obj] Error 1

ERROR : root.compile : when module_path ran, error: 2

DEBUG : root.compile : Stop thread : Thread-100
Flags and options : -1- -d -ml -w -f- -x- -v -R- -vi -RT- -P -DCAD
Generating OPT C Options File
Generating OPT ASM Options File
Compiling ../../../../source/lrc.c
"C:\Bc45\bin\bcc"  +c.opt -c -olrc.obj ../../../../source/lrc.c
Borland C++ 4.52 Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 Borland International
../../../../source/lrc.c:
Compiling ../../../../source/c_des.c
"C:\Bc45\bin\bcc"  +c.opt -c -oc_des.obj ../../../../source/c_des.c
Borland C++ 4.52 Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 Borland International
../../../../source/c_des.c:
Error: Unable to execute command 'tasm.exe'
WARNING : root.compile : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
WARNING : root.compile : MODULE FAILED
WARNING : root.compile : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I have already checked:

- if tasm.exe is really in C:\Bc45\bin\bcc (it is),
- all my environment variables,
- the folders rights (full control)
- when I enter TASM in CMD, it show correctly the help of TASM
- when I execute it within Borland and with directly ASM files, it's OK

  ```
   Flags and Options : -1- -d -ml -w -f- -x- -v -R- -vi -P -RT- -DMAGIC510 
   -DCADHEX -D4WIRES -DCAD1 -DAGP_2 -DTERM_TYPE=1
   Generating OPT C Options File
   Generating OPT ASM Options File
   Assembling ../../../../source/bcpp31.asm
   Turbo Assembler  Version 4.1  Copyright (c) 1988, 1996 Borland International

   Assembling file:   ..\..\..\..\source\bcpp31.asm
   Assembling for the large memory model
   Paradigm LOCATE Borland C++ 3.10 Startup Support
   *Warning* ..\..\..\..\source\bcpp31.asm(657) Module is pass dependent - com
   patibility pass was done
   Error messages:    None
   Warning messages:  1
   Passes:            2
   Remaining memory:  391k

   Compiling ../../../../source/bcpprtl.asm
   Turbo Assembler  Version 4.1  Copyright (c) 1988, 1996 Borland International

   Assembling file:   ..\..\..\..\source\bcpprtl.asm
   Assembling for the large memory model
   *Warning* ..\..\..\..\source\bcpprtl.asm(142) Module is pass dependent - compati
   bility pass was done
   Error messages:    None
   Warning messages:  1
   Passes:            2
   Remaining memory:  398k

   Build complete bcpp31.obj bcpprtl.obj are up-to-date
  ```

And, it worked fine in an other computer with the same OS (Seven Entreprise SP 1).

If you have other any ideas, I shall be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Could any of the resulting full path names (e.g., `C:\this\that\etc.`) be too long ?   There is an old DOS limit; I forget what it is.

Comment: Well, actually, it could. But I had this problem early and even Borland did not work. Because they are at the same level, I doubt that's it. I still checked, the longest path is 50 characters and it seems to me that the max should be 128.

Comment: I have tried with the other computer and, even with a long long path, there is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the path to Borland in PATH is within first few (128) characters, if not move it to beginning. Check if there is no other tasm.exe than Borland in your PATH.